# qt drawing outlined text with QPainterPath

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter, qpainterpath

i have to draw outlined striked out text on QImage like that:

[image]

I do it as follows:

```
QPainter painter(this);

QPainterPath path;

QFont font;
font.setPixelSize(95);
font.setStrikeOut(true);
font.setBold(true);

path.addText(10, 150, font, "lololo");

painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
painter.setBrush(Qt::red);

painter.drawPath(path);
```

and get this result:

[image]

As one can see the striking out line has zebra-like fill. How i can fill it completely with painter's brush?

I tried to change QPainter composition mode with no success. Also i tried to use QPainterPathStroker with the same result.

Sure i can draw striked out text with ordinary font (not striked out) plus rectangle, but it isn't a beautiful solution.

Comment: @eyllanesc i added the picture

Comment: Try `path.setFillRule(Qt::WindingFill)` before the `addText`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia tried, result is the same

Comment: @eyllanesc similar, but not the same. i want to get picture like at the top of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to perform operations between 2 paths with and without strike:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QImage image(300, 200, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    image.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QPoint p(30, 150);
    QString text = "lololo";

    QFont font;
    font.setPixelSize(95);
    font.setBold(true);

    QPainterPath path1;
    font.setStrikeOut(true);
    path1.addText(p, font, text);
    font.setStrikeOut(false);
    QPainterPath path2;
    path2.addText(p, font, text);

    QPainterPath strike = (path1 + path2) - (path1 & path2);
    //                      \---join---/    \-intersection-/
    QPainter painter(&image);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
    painter.drawPath(path2);
    painter.drawPath(strike);
    painter.end();

    QLabel w;
    w.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]